# Is it OK to use awesome vueJS component in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Vue.js has a rich echo systems with several free utilities, tools and component. Particularly interesting is the list of freely available curated list of vue components ["awesome-vue"](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue).

My question is how safe these components list is to use in the production use case scenarios? What precautions one must follow to use them as-is or is it better to write your own components for production use to ensure safety, security and minimize potential code breaks or defects etc.

Comment: Is it ok? Generally, yes. How better is one component from another? A good metric is the number of GitHub stars. At least 20, for starters. Another is how frequent the commits are. If the last commit was a year ago, the component is probably dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no curation on this list regarding safety. All the components listed there have their own creators so it's impossible to say if they are safe to use in production or not. In case you are doing something critical with these components, it's advisable to audit the code yourself as it should be available on most cases.

Assuming the components are on npm, you can pin the version numbers of the components to always use the same component, so that way there's no risk of code breaking as the code for the certain version will always be the same.